# How can I use best_in_place gem with Bootstrap Form controls?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, best-in-place

I want to use the best_in_place gem with Bootstrap's form controls. I can't seem to be able to combine both.

My best_in_place snippet

```
<div class="form-control" >
   <dt><%= best_in_place @user, :email, :as => :textarea %></dt>
</div>
```

My Bootstrap snippet

```
<form>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
    </div>
</form>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

[image]

https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place

[image]

Any ideas how this can be done?

This works with Validations

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="email" class="form-control" >
  </div>
</form>
```

But using best_in_place, Bootstrap validations not working.

```
</form>
 <div class="form-control" input type="email" >
  <%= best_in_place @user, :email, :as => :input %>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this code

```
</form>
 <div class="form-control" input type="email" >
  <%= best_in_place @user, :email, :as => :input %>
 </div>
</form>
```

But used another method (gem 'validates_email_format_of') to validate input, could not get both to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
    </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Ghost, I'm not sure how your snippet is helpful, it's same as my earlier Bootstrap snippet. I need to use best_in_place within bootstrap form.

Comment: oww sorry dude i think u need 2nd pic design